# Randomly shuffling all files in a directory?

Tags: bash, variables, random, directory, shuffle

I am trying to find a solution with bash to shuffle a directory full of 2x3000 files of the type:

.mp4

.json (stores the metadata).

The .mp4 and .json are connected to each other so, the problem is:

I can shuffle both individually, but this loses the indirect connection in the process. So I would need a code, which stores the random value, into a variable and assign it to my .mp4+json package each.

The folder contains

- 1.mp4
- 2.mp4
- 3.mp4
- 3000.mp4

and also

- 1.json
- 2.json
- 3.json
- 3000.json

I´ve looked everywhere on the platform but didnt find a satisfying solution and its beyond my bash skills!

This was my base code:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" $RANDOM-"$i"; done

paste <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" * | shuf) |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r from to; do mv -- "$from" "$to.mp4"; done

for f in *.mp4; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp4}"; done
```

Thank you!

cheers Michael Schuller

Comment: You can use `mv $i.mp4 $newname.mp4 && mv $i.json $newname.json`.  This way the json file gets renamed if the rename of the mp4 worked. Look on $i, generate a new random name for each $i.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply! I tried that, but its not working yet:

for i in *; do mv "$i" $RANDOM-"$i"; done



paste <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" * | shuf) |


  while IFS=$'\t' read -r from to mv "$i.mp4" "$newname.mp4 && mv "$i.json"

 "$newname.json"; done

Comment: Would you be able to write down the script with me? I am lost ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    # Remove prefix ./
    filenoprefix="${file#./}"
    # Remove extension
    filenoext="${filenoprefix%.*}"
    # New name is random-oldfilename
    newfilename="$RANDOM-$filenoext"
    # Rename files .mp4 and .json
    mv "$filenoext".mp4 "$newfilename".mp4 && mv "$filenoext".json "$newfilename".json
done
```

- the `find ... | while` is from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- variable substitution is used to remove the `./` prefix `find` adds to results.
- the extension is removed from the filename
- the new filename is a concatenation of `$RANDOM` and the original filename
- and finally, 2 `mv` commands separated by `&&`.

**Note**: this works ok if you run the script in the same directory as where the files are.

**Note 2**: this works ok if all files are in the same directory.  I did not make it general since you mentioned that all files are in the same directory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found some help in the ubuntu discord!

Here is the solution

```
for i in *.mp4; do
  noext="${i%.*}";
  newname="$RANDOM";
  mv "${noext}.json" "${newname}-${noext}.json";
  mv "${noext}.mp4" "${newname}-${noext}.mp4";
done
```